# Embossing an edge-loop

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edges

This question follows from [Constructing and bevelling a pie-slice](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10786/constructing-and-bevelling-a-pie-slice)

I'm trying to bring definition to the top edge of a solid geometric object.

EDIT: I'm trying to achieve something like this:
[image]
... The important thing is that the edge is clearly defined, rather than exactly how it looks. So I'm interested in any technique for doing this. I'm focusing on this one because it's the only one I currently know how to do.

First I go into edit mode, edge-select, CTRL+RightClick to select an edgeloop, and create a vertex group:

[image]

Then I attempt to apply wireframe modifier:

[image]

As you can see, it doesn't work. 
However, if I try the same technique on a cube, it does work. (I've included the cube in the picture, although it isn't the best screenshot, sorry about that).

How to get this effect working?

And is there any other technique to bring the edges out? Could I somehow extrude a square/hexagon through that entire edge loop?

Someone on IRC suggested bézier + Bevel-object. I like the sound of this, but would I have to first create the curve, and then independently create an object for the border using bevel object, and then create the actual solid object by extruding the curve downwards?

Comment: could you add a sketch or photo of what to want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, I've added an image and a little explanation. The main thing is to get a well-defined border rather than exactly how that border needs to look.

Comment: From your description it looks like you have found a problem with many of Blenders tools.  If you change an objects location and dimensions in Object mode then a lot of other tools will fail to function properly.  Several tools have been updated to fix this but not all of them.  Try to remember to alter your model in Edit unless it can avoided and also remember this shortcut(in Object mode)  Ctrl-A, to use 'Apply -> Rotation and Scale', also 'Apply -> Location'

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is by beveling, then extruding:

[image]

What I did in the gif:

1. Enter edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
2. Enter face select mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>*> Face*)
3. Select a face on the surface that I want to select, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to select the entire surface.
4. *3D view > Header > Select > Select Boundary loop*:

   [image]
5. Bevel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>)
6. Extrude and cancel transform (<kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>) See [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/10655/599) for details on what pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> does.
7. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to scale along the normals.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I was struggling with the original GIF!